# Parameterise linear combination of cosines

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, parametric

How do I parameterise the following implicit surface?

$$ \cos x + \cos y + \cos z = 0 $$

Motivation for this problem comes from attempting to find stable motion for an object balanced on one point. The equation seems so simple, but I really have no idea how to solve this problem. Apparently the surface approximates the [Schwarz P minimal surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_minimal_surface#Schwarz_P_.28.22Primitive.22.29), however I do not have any knowledge of the theory behind that.

Answer (score 2):

The first octant of the "Fermi surface" can be parametrized as
$$
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
  \cos^{-1}
  \left[
    -\dfrac{u}{2}+v\left( 1-\dfrac{|u|}{2} \right)
  \right] \\[5pt]
  \cos^{-1}
  \left[ 
    -\dfrac{u}{2}-v\left( 1-\dfrac{|u|}{2} \right)
  \right] \\[5pt]
  \cos^{-1} u
\end{pmatrix}$$

where $u$, $v\in [-1,1]$.

To make it periodic,

$$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
  2\pi \left \lfloor \dfrac{i+1}{2} \right \rfloor+(-1)^{i}
  \cos^{-1} \left[ -\dfrac{u}{2}+v\left( 1-\dfrac{|u|}{2} \right) \right] \\[5pt]
  2\pi \left \lfloor \dfrac{j+1}{2} \right \rfloor+(-1)^{j}
  \cos^{-1} \left[ -\dfrac{u}{2}-v\left( 1-\dfrac{|u|}{2} \right) \right] \\[5pt]
  2\pi \left \lfloor \dfrac{k+1}{2} \right \rfloor+(-1)^{k}\cos^{-1} u
\end{pmatrix}$$

where $i$, $j$, $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

For first "Brillouin zone", take $i$, $j$, $k=-1$, $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Just to get an idea of the surface:

[image]

The curves of different colour correspond to different values of $\cos z$
with $z = k \pi/4$.

Comment: Thank you for uploading the graph. I did already have something similar. How do I parameterise each of those level sets? Also, is there a way to do the parameterisation so that the resulting solution clearly shows the cubic symmetry of the surface?

Comment: The red cell morphs into a green cell, if we increase $z$. I do not know a parameterization for the resulting surface in 3D space. My expectation is that this surface is only locally parameterizable.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to solve $ \cos (r \cos \theta) + \cos (r \sin \theta) = a $ for $a \in [-1, 1]$ in terms of $r$, using elementary functions?