# What type of curve is described by $\cos{x}+\cos{x}\cos{y}+\cos{y}=0$?

Tags: curves, plane-curves, implicit-function

Does the curve by the function $$\cos{x}+\cos{x}\cos{y}+\cos{y}=0\\x=[-2\pi/3,2\pi/3],\; y=[-2\pi/3,2\pi/3]$$ belong to any known curve family? Examples of curves can be found in Wikipedia ([Link1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallery_of_curves), [Link2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_curves)) but the longest list with $\approx 1000$ curves you find [here](https://www.2dcurves.com/).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This implicit equation can be written

$$(1+\cos x)(1+\cos y)=1$$

Using a classical trigonometric formula:

$$4(\cos(x/2)\cos(y/2))^2=1$$

$$2\cos(x/2)\cos(y/2)=\pm 1$$

Due to invariance with respect to changes $x \to -x, y \to -y$ (in connection with symmetries with respect to coordinate axes), one can reduce the study to the first quadrant with equation:

$$\cos(y/2)=\frac{1}{2 \cos(x/2)}$$

finally giving a cartesian equation for the curve in the first quadrant:

$$y=2 \arccos \left(\frac{1}{2 \cos(x/2)}\right) $$

This form doesn't evoke more anything known than the implicit form (but see the Edit below).

A first check : if $x=0$ we get $y=2 \frac{\pi}{3}$ which is the point $(0,2 \frac{\pi}{3}\approx 2.09)$ on your curve.

Remark: there is also another symmetry with respect to line bissector $y=x$.

**Important edit:** With the help of Geogebra, I have found a very good fit of this curve with the following so-called ["squircle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squircle) with equation

$$|x|^{2.42}+|y|^{2.42}=5.95\tag{1}$$

as we can see on the following representation (the red curve with equation (1) hides almost completely the initial curve, in black).
It would be interesting to understand why such a good fit exists.

[image]

Comment: In fact, take a look at this past [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3054240) of mine : your curve can be seen as a level set curve of a 3D surface.

Comment: The squircle $|x|^n+|y|^n=r^n$ must go through the points $[\pi/2,\pi/2]$ and $[\arccos{(-1/3)},\pi/3]$. This leads to the equations $r=2^{1/n}\pi/2$ and $\arccos^n{(-1/3)}+(\pi/3)^n-2(\pi/2)^n=0$ with $n\approx 2.5309771870579384152$.

Comment: If you plot the difference of both curves you see that they are identical only at the 2 fitted points and deviate elsewhere up to a difference of 0.0016.

Comment: I agree of course that we can only aim at an approximation. But the best global approximation is not necessarily obtained by constraining the approximation curve to pass through the summital points.

Comment: A Guasti-Squircle fits even better. But actually I am looking for an identity not for similar functions.

Comment: I will look at Guasti-Squircle. I understand your point. IMHO, I am afraid there is no classical type of curves to which this one can be referred (in an exact manner)

Answer (score 2):

You may say $2$-D version or cross-section of Fermi-surfaces (especially for cubic system).

See the posts [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1825682/parameterise-linear-combination-of-cosines), [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/253464/fermi-surface-reconstruction-and-fermi-pockets) and also [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/584751/fermi-surfaces-of-alkali-metals).

[image]

[image]

**Addendum**

See also an article in *Mathematical Intelligencer* [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00283-018-9790-x).

Comment: Which specific Fermi surface and which cross-section do you mean?

Comment: One example is $$\cos x+\cos y+\cos z+\cos x \cos y \cos z=a$$ Then put $z=0$.

Comment: This is just a formula, where is the connection to a Fermi Surface?

Comment: That is equal energy surface of crystal lattice in reciprocal space.  As a result, it is periodic and relates with implicit equation of Fourier series in $\boldsymbol{k}$ space.  As you asked about family of curves and so on, you can assign any collective terms.  For example, Borwein studied some lattice (multiple) sums and called them Madelung constants as appearing in chemistry.

Comment: Moreover, many Fermi surfaces look like Schwarz minimal surfaces which can be approximated by implicit equations involving trigomometric functions in $x$, $y$ and $z$.

Comment: Very interesting answer.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for your response.

Answer (score -1):

It approximates to  fourth, sixth, eighth order ellipses depending on number of chosen terms in binomial series.

Taking the lowest second order terms only

$$ (1+\cos x)(1+\cos y)=1 ; \to x^2+y^2= 2$$

is a circle radius $\sqrt 2 $ centered at origin.

If instead of $\sqrt 2 $ we take on higher values for the exponent, i.e., as $ 2n \to \infty$... so that

$$x^{2000}+y^{2000}\to (\sqrt 2)^{2000}$$

approximating to the unit square forming more pointed vertices at corners of the figures in the process.

Iirc, a reasonably large value of $2n$ is chosen to approximate aircraft window cutout contours in aircraft fuselage usage adapted to out-of-plane 3d profiles.

Comment: this approximation is far from the original figure.